# Render a web form to a PDF as it is (as we see in print preview in Chrome) PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf, mpdf

I'm new to php web development. I have a php web form that I created fit into the letter size paper (using css). When I hit print on browser (Chrome) I can see it nicely on print view (as PDF). But My requirement is to safe this pdf on server when client submit the form. I already figured out how to save the pdf in server. But I'm still struggling to render the pdf same as I see in the browser print viewer.
I tried mPDF and html2pdf. mPDF rendered to a weird looking pdf. May be my settings are wrong. Please help me to figure this out.

Thank you.

What I used so far..

```
function get_web_page( $url )
{
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
    );

    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;
    return $header;
}

$Get_url = "http://www.sample.com/application.php" ;
$array = get_web_page($Get_url);

$html = $array['content'];

include("mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new mPDF('c'); 


$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output('Applications/filename.pdf','d');
```

What I want:
[image: Web form in browser] Web form in browser

[image: Web form in print preview] How it looks in print preview. (How I want it to save in the server)

Comment: Tyr using wkhtmltopdf. I have found that it renders pretty much exactly the same as you see on the browser.

Comment: I'm reading about it. I might consider that. Thank you. But I'm looking for something easy, which not much involve installations.  But I will give this a try.